# Delete Trigger failing to update count in another table

Tags: sql, informix

I am using Informix database.

TableA contains the id of a client.
TableB contains the number of error on that id. i.e {id and count}

In TableA I have delete triggers written, so that if anyone deletes an entry in TableA then, a stored procedure in the delete trigger is executed which decreased the count in tableB for that client by 1.

Now, there was a strange behavior that after deleting many entries in TableA, it took more than 15 minutes to update tableB and in one instance hours.

Can someone please suggest what is reason for this kind of behavior. I am not able to understand as this is very plain and simple and this issue should not have arised.

Please note that I am not able to recreate this issue.
What might be plausible explanation for this kind of behavior.

Comment: why do posters continue to post descriptions of code??? This is a programming site. Post teh code FFS!

Comment: Is the problem that it is slow, or that it gets the answer wrong?  The title suggests 'wrong'; the question suggests 'slow'.  You say 'delete triggers'; do you mean 'more than one ON DELETE trigger on TableA'?  Are you sure you really need to keep derived data in Table B?  Which version of Informix running on which platform?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler....srry there is only one delete trigger...but once an entry/entries are deleted from tableA, it calls a stored procedure which updates the count for that client in tableB by num-1 and finally to zero...in that stored procedure there is "set lock mode to wait 20" at the top ...now there is update trigger on tableB which again calls a stored procedure that has "set lock mode wait". Normally it functions well if I am trying it replicate this issue,the count in tableB is becoming zero which should be the case but sometimes it behaves abnormally and it takes lot of time.

Comment: Can this "set lock mode wait" in second stored procedure cause some issue ? I am using Informix version 8

Comment: Version 8 — XPS? So the problem is the speed, not the accuracy of the result? While we like to be fast and right, we prefer right and slow to wrong and fast. Yes, the SET LOCK MODE WAIT could be an issue, though it would be an issue mainly if multiple people are editing the data in Table A concurrently (one person shouldn't be blocking themselves — but that one person would have to be running one session). If you're running XPS, you'll have been using it for a long time. Was it 'always' a problem or did something change recently? Can you give a precise version? 8.32.FC3 or thereabouts?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler....sorry for the wrong details previously... I am using INFORMIX-SQL Version 9.40.UC8W1X1 .. you say that if multiple persons are concurrently deleting the data in tableA, then set lock mode wait can cause issue here. Can you please explain and suggest a way to replicate this issue as this issue took place in production database and I need to come up with at least some explanation to how this can be avoided in future. Thanks !!!